# Store char array value error(c++)

Tags: c++

i'm trying to make the c++ program that manage student list but got into error from the very beginning. Here's my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
struct  Candidate
{
  char id[5];
char fullname[30];
int reading, listening,total;
};
int main ()

{
struct Candidate can[100];
int n=0;
do {
    cout << "Input number of candidate:";
    cin >> n;
    if (n <= 0 || n>=50)
        cout << "Candidate number must be between 0 and 50:\n";
} while (n <= 0 || n>=50);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Input information for candidate number " << i + 1 << endl;
    cin.ignore(32323, '\n');
    cout << "Input ID(only 5 character):";
    gets(can[i].id);
    cout << "Input full name:";
    gets(can[i].fullname);

    do {
        cout << "Input reading mark:";
        cin >> can[i].reading;
        if(can[i].reading < 5 || can[i].reading>495)
            cout<<"Your reading mark is not between 5 and 495\n";
    } while (can[i].reading < 5 || can[i].reading>495);
    do {
        cout << "Input listening mark:";
        cin >> can[i].listening;
        if(can[i].listening < 5 || can[i].listening>495)
            cout<<"Your listening mark is not between 5 and 495\n";
    } while (can[i].listening < 5 || can[i].listening>495);


    can[i].total = can[i].reading + can[i].listening;
}
cout << endl << can[0].id<<endl;
}
```

So i got an output like this:

```
Input number of candidate:1


Input information for candidate number 1


Input ID(only 5 character):EW2RR


Input full name:Test1


Input reading mark:344


Input listening mark:233

EW2RRTest1
```

It seems like the value of fullname is written continually to ID. I have tried a lot of way to fix but couldn't figure out. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use `std::string` and associated stream functions. This is c++ after all. Failing that `fgets` is a better choice, as you are able to pass the buffer length.

Comment: Looking at `"Input ID (only 5 characters)"`, you should use `char id[6]` instead of `char id[5]`. There are probably a bunch of other problems, you should learn how to debug your code (the bottom line in your question implies that you are trying to fix it without debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every string if you have a string length of N you must have char array of size at least N+1 for '\0' which indicates that the string ends here for cout to stop printing.

In your case you declared char array of size 5 and you fill all 5 with characters so '\0' is put somewhere else. Notice that "id" and "fullname" locate next to each other , so my best guess is that gets put '\0' of when you scan "ID" which should be "id[5]" to "fullname[0]", and then when you scan "FULLNAME" , it replaces this '\0' , so "id" has no termination point and must use termination point of "fullname". That's why it seems like fullname has been appended to id. Be aware that this is not the default behavior , the program may act different on other machines.

Also , gets() is a broken function , if you use cin or scanf before , you should flush your stdin first by calling

```
fflush(stdin);
```

before you use gets() because sometimes '\n' is left in the stdin but in your case this was taken care by

```
cin.ignore(32323, '\n');
```

Using fgets() as Paul Rooney stated is much more preferable. I myself also had a lot of problems with gets.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a terminal `'\0'` char at the end of every string.

When the ID gets printed, the code (`cout`) won't stop til it hits a `NULL`.

This is called overrunning your buffer.

Comment: I should be precise: let me change my terms.

Comment: (OK; lesson learned:  don't hit <CR> in a comment.)  when I say "string" above, replace that with "char array."  Paul Rooney make a good point when he mentions a string object.  The string class hides the required terminal NULL from you, so you don't need to deal with that nitty gritty.  Along the same vein, it's a whole lot easier to manipulate strings with the C++ string class than with the C string.h library.  (Except for output!  I have never been able to see any value writing or executing output with cout over printf.  Fortunately for you, you don't need to worry about efficiency.)

Comment: @Poomrokc explains how you need to think about managing these terminal `\0`s.  The only revision I would make to his explanation:  Strike _"my best guess,"_ as his expectation is _exactly_ what happens.   Further, if you fill `fullname[]` first, and then fill `id[]`, your output would be along the lines of `id="EW2RR"` and `full name=""`.  That is, `fullname[]` would appear to be (and actually by definition _*would be*_) an empty string, despite your having populated it.